# Error: Cannot convert argument 1 from 'char [80]' to 'char'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass an int to a struct. I have to validate it and the class instructions say I have to run it through a function.

Here's the error message:

`C2664: 'int get_id(char)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'char [80]' to 'char'`

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <exception>


//functions called
int get_id(char);

//structs
struct fileinfo
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    char state[5];
    char dis_code;
    float balance;
    char due_date[40];
};


//why is it void?
int main(void)
{
    fileinfo info[80];

    int ct = 0;
    char more = 'y';
    char buff[80];

    while (more == 'y')
    {

        printf("ID: ");
        gets_s(buff);

        info[ct].id = get_id(buff);
        printf("this is ID: %i", info[ct].id);

        printf("Do you want to enter another? ");
        gets_s(buff);
        more = buff[0];
    }

    system("pause");

}//end main

int get_id(char buf[])
{
    int id;
    char buffer[85];
    bool check = false;

    id = atoi(buf);
    while (check == false)
    {
        if (id > 998)
        {
            printf("\n This ID number is too large, please re-enter: ");
            gets_s(buffer);
            id = atoi(buffer);
            check = false;
        }
        else
        {
            check = true;
        }
    }

    return id;
}
```

Comment: prototype `int get_id(char);` to `int get_id(char*);` and `gets_s(buff);` to `gets_s(buff, 79);`

Comment: "If you guys would kindly not troll my account like last time with negative reports on here." Did you take it up with Meta? Because if there was genuine abuse, I'm sure they would love to hear about it. It sounds more like the all-too-common user refusing to take criticism or accept negative feedback to me.

Comment: i never used meta. I will have to explore that option later on after I get done with this class. 
I like the site and it seems like i got really common problems. I am just not fast enough to answer other people's questions.

Comment: That's not C, but C++ with cstdio, fstream, exception, cstring...

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks this is right. Wow, how did i miss that.

Comment: @Jens I have been adding more and more of those #include files. The instructor never marked them. ;) 
It is a very wired class. Other questions I have had about this class has pointed towards this being C by the StackOverflow community. And the book says C++, the instructor never says one way or the another. But in this class we can only use int, float, and char arrays. This instructor wants a ton of arrays.

Comment: So, C-style in C++-land? Beware low-flying tomatoes then.

Comment: `gets_s(buff);` to `gets_s(buff, sizeof buff);`

Comment: Your instructor probably teaches you C++ as an incremental improvement over C, without introducing the more powerful and interesting C++ features. It is a possible but not particularly effective way of using C++. People who are taught this way are often unsure about the difference between the two languages. If you are not sure what you are studying, perhaps it could be a good idea to ask your instructor a direct question.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yea tell me about it.